# How to select data using like with out consider after character in laravel or sql

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, select, eloquent

I have a table call labels_table.

---

| id | label |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A_1_1 |
| 2 | A_1_2 |
| 3 | A_2_1 |
| 4 | A_4_1 |
| 5 | A_10_1 |
| 6 | A_11_1 |

I need to select all the labels for A_1 group. A_1_1 and  A_1_2 should be the correct labels.

I used the following query.

**sql**

```
SELECT * from `label_table` where `label` LIKE `A_1_%`;
```

**Larval**

```
$identifier = “A_1”;

 $this->model->where('label', 'LIKE',$identifier.'_%')->get();
```

But both SQL and laravel queries returns all A_1_1, A_1_2, A_10_1 and A_11_1. But I need to get only A_1_1 and  A_1_2.

Please explain what’s the issue here and give me a solution. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LIKE` allows you to escape the wildcard characters.  The default is backslash:

```
where `label` LIKE 'A\_1\_%';
```

However, you can also set your own:

```
where `label` LIKE 'A$_1$_%' ESCAPE '$';
```

Or use regular expressions:

```
where label REGEXP '^A_1_'
```

Comment: nice. I used REGEXP and It worked!
I have written it using laravel.

`$identifier = “A_1”;


 $this->model->where('label', 'regexp','^'.$identifier.'_')->get();`


thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Underscore symbol in a LIKE predicate means any single symbol. Escape it to use as a literal "_".

```
SELECT * 
FROM label_table 
WEHRE label LIKE 'A\_1\_%'
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e79f1d3b8f70f3fa5ce83625478e8088)

Comment: thanks. it's working only for the above data. if I have values like A_1_10 and A_1_11 under the A_1 group it's wrong.
your query returns only values from A_1_1 to A_1_9. it doesn't return values like A_1_10, A_1_11.

Comment: Adde the fiddle